# Azure CLI 2.0: az vm update --set/--remove does not work?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am attempting to remove and set tags on a VM, but am getting the error *unrecognized arguments*.

For example, removing a tag:

`az vm update –-resource-group MyResourceGroup –-name MyTestVM --remove tags.myNewTagName1`

and setting a tag:

`az vm update --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyTestVM –-set tags.myNewTagName1=myNewTagValue1`

Both examples are from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tag). I'm running v2.0.30 on Mac OS 10.12.x.

Can anyone else confirm this and/or have it work for them? I haven't found any bugs listed in the [issues db](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what was wrong. The syntax of the command is correct and works. However, I copied the command out of the documentation and it has a different character for the dashes/hyphens that the AZ CLI does not accept.

If you copy the samples, just re-type the dashes with the standard ones on your keyboard.

I had posted it this as an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5976